# UML - Aggregate an association, is it even possible?

Tags: uml, system, ooad

I am bit new to all this UML, so I hope you all would bear with me and my rookie question.

During OOA when you'll alway draw a domain model. It shows the concepts, it's attributes, and the relations (association) between each concepts.

But I haven't understood Whole - to - part associations yet.
As far as i've understood, it has something to do with a concept  beeing  associated to multiple concepts, am i right?..

And is it possible to aggregate an association, or is it strictly concepts which can be aggregated???

My confusing may be due to the fact that i am bit unclear on when to use aggregation in the first place...?? could someone clarify it for me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is vague, but let's start here from IBM's description:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell

Search for aggregation and composition.

Basically, aggregation is used for a class with multiple dependent components, like a car and its parts.  When a car is totaled, the wheels can be removed. The wheels and may have other purposes (inventoried, repaired, recycled, etc.).  Composition exists when a component's lifecycle is dependent on the parent class lifecycle.  An example of composition is a business and its operations (like its loading dock).  When the business closes, the loading dock is no longer necessary so both instances are deleted.

Comment: Is it like having a class  (concept) called animal and from animal it has attributes. Each attribute can bee seen as an component??

To be more specifik about my question, does Aggregation only apply to classes, or also association between classes (Consepts)

Comment: Not like an animal and its attributes.  The attributes are the variables of a given class.  Aggregation is an association between classes.  It's really a question of how complex your system is.  If you have multiple non-trivial components then you model can model each component as associated classes.  I would suggest reading a book about object oriented analysis and design.  This type of problem is well understood and described.

Comment: But could an aggregation or composition exist for an association.

Comment: Aggregation and composition are forms of association.  One would not associate associations.  One associates classes, components, subsystems, and systems.

Comment: Could you do anything on an association??

Comment: Associations, in C++ at any rate, are often implemented as pointers to instances of a class.  Associations are used to navigate the relationships between classes.

Comment: Would it be able to add some kind of exta information during the association, between the 2 classes.

Comment: You can add directionality, roles, and multiplicity.

Comment: The reason why i am asking is because my lecturer just let pass with this domain model, where I did some thing like this..

http://snag.gy/m7bSG.jpg i don't understand how come it is correct, He praised me for doing it right, which i didn't understand cause in my head it is exactly the opposite. I totally agree with you  @Bruce..  he said it is because one of my postconditions is that class 3 should be associated with class 2, and how anyone would would do it.

Comment: What you've drawn is an association class.  I have never seen one that uses composition, but that doesn't matter.  See: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsarthlp/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcassnclss.html

Comment: Ohh... this look good Bruce..  but woud the postcondition then be to have an assoociation between the student and the course or between the enrollment and the course or something different?

Comment: I don't understand your use of the word "postcondition".  In writing the code, the student can find information about the course.  The course cannot find information about the student.  Some other class (registrar) could use the enrollment class to find students and the classes in which they are enrolled.

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Ahh.  So the way you've modeled it, the reservation is the association class between the guest and the room.  The analogy with the IBM example is student:course:enrollment <--> guest:room:reservation.  The diagram showing the relationships is the postcondition.

Comment: So what I am doing is exactly described at 
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsarthlp/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcassnclss.html
Would it be incorrect to change my postcondition to s that class 3 should be associated with class 2

Comment: Sorry, you cannot change your postcondition.  The postcondition is the textual description and is a requirement.  I would not change the diagram.  The class association associates class 3 with classes 1 and 2.

Comment: I would if knew how ?.. It says that my rep is too low.